# Impdp 12c takes table original size

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, impdp, expdp

I want to import one of my schema "vvs1" to r&d database with content=metdata_only. expdp works perfect but when i am going to import on r&d server it takes tables original size.

for example:-
I have 1 table vvs.xyz with size of 10 GB. i am taking structure backup only. now import on r&d server it creates a table structure with 10 GB size.
i want only table with default size while created.

expdp syntax:

```
expdp vvs/1 full=Y CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY directory=DATAPUMP_DIR dumpfile=full.dmp logfile=full.log KEEP_MASTER=Y
```

impdp syntax:

```
impdp vvs/1  CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY directory=DATAPUMP_DIR dumpfile=full.dmp logfile=full_impdp.log schemas=vvs
```

main database :-**Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production**

r&d database:-
**Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production**

Comment: It will use the init and next segment sizes when creating the table.  You will have to create it manually before you do the import.

Comment: Just out of interest, are you really using standard in prod, and EE in R&D?

Comment: yes, i did this only on dev & testing server only

Answer (score 2):

Typically caused by the segment attributes of the tables.

You can use `TRANSFORM=SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES:N`, so the tables will be created with default options.

You can use `TRANSFORM=SEGMENT_CREATION:N` as well, so your segments will not be created at all, unless deferred segment creation is disabled in your database.

[TRANSFORM](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/datapump-import-utility.html#GUID-64FB67BD-EB67-4F50-A4D2-5D34518E6BDB)

[DEFERRED_SEGMENT_CREATION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/DEFERRED_SEGMENT_CREATION.html#GUID-29066C9A-1CC7-48E4-A278-BB9678EE3362)

Comment: thanks a lot @Balazs Papp, from this parameter it works proper